# Firebase analytics - how to see all the users properties in an event detail view

Tags: android, ios, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

An event detail shows how many users triggered that event and how many times.
[image]

Is there a way to also see a list of all the users who triggered it and see each user's properties?

Comment: I have the same question and have been searching for it for a few hours. I believe that the answer is that Firebase Analytics simply don't have this very basic feature. I really hope that I am wrong.

Comment: Yes I think so too, I just exported the data to bigquery and used it there.

Comment: Any news on this after 2 years?

Comment: It's still not supported sadly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in BigQuery or creating app+web property in Google Analytics and connect it with Firebase. [image: how to see all the users properties in an event detail view]

Answer (score 0):

You can not filter by user properties.  Click on events, select the event you are interested in, and then add a filter and press apply.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

See [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users) for further details on the following code:

```
import FirebaseAuth
func userProperties(){
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if let user = user {
        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project.
        // Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server,
        // if you have one. Use getTokenWithCompletion:completion: instead.
        let uid = user.uid
        let email = user.email
        let photoURL = user.photoURL
        var multiFactorString = "MultiFactor: "
        for info in user.multiFactor.enrolledFactors {
            multiFactorString += info.displayName ?? "[DispayName]"
            multiFactorString += " "
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```